# Faint Screen Flickering (only in DX apps?)

Tags: graphics-card, screen-tearing

I have recently bought an MSI Radeon R9 270 GPU, and while it seems to work alright, I've been getting this very weird issue, mainly in games.

There happens to be a very faint screen flickering all over the screen, and it's happening constantly. It looks like a bunch of very faint white lines all over the screen, sometimes they are closer together. It is better seen on dark backgrounds, especially if the scene is more or less static. It even happens in menus, which is weird.

I don't think it's an issue with the card itself (i.e. the card isn't faulty), because I went and replaced the card and the issue persists. It isn't an issue with the motherboard, because I got another motherboard too (for different reasons, but bear with me). I don't think it's an issue with the cable, because when I used Intel's integrated graphics the issue did not occur. My monitor only supports VGA (it's about 6 or so years old), so I am currently using a DVI to VGA adapter. When I used integrated graphics without an adapter it worked fine. The issue also appears to happen only in DX applications, and doesn't appear in OpenGL applications (though I'll have to verify). I tried different driver versions and to no avail. VSync does not remove the issue entirely, though the flickering "slows" down, so to say.

I tried searching around very hard, but the only issue similiar to mine that I managed to find is described here: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1960272/amd-radeon-270-asus-screen-flickering.html

To sum it up: 
* Does not happen while running on integrated graphics.
* Motherboard is not faulty.
* GPU is not faulty.
* Only appears to happen in DX applications.
* Does not appear to be a cable/monitor problem (I have no way to verify that though).

So I have come here to ask what else can I look into to gain some more insight into this? What else might be a cause to this issue, considering the conditions? What tests can I do to narrow down the issue?

Any input is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would use another adapter. - *integrated graphics without an **adapter** it worked fine*

Comment: I had 3 different (two of which were brand new), and there were no differences unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had an old Gateway monitor that decided to go on me and flickering, lines, and banding where all telltale symptoms. I'd try it on another monitor for sure. Worst case, you can now split screen. Best case, you have a new monitor to replace one on its way out. If you know anyone with a monitor that is known to be in fine shape, try them first.